# Converting feet to inches

Tags: c++, calculator

I'm making a calculator, and I'm trying to convert feet to inches, I know I can do feet * 12.0, but I run into problems when trying to convert say 5"11. I ask the user "Enter your height(ft in) with a space between(for example, 5 11 would be five feet 11 inches), I don't know how based on what the user inputs, I can take the height, and multiply the first portion(the feet) like 5 * 12 then add say 11(implying they put 5 11) to the (5 * 12) calculation, in order to get 71". I tried wording this as best as possible, if anyone needs clarification I'll try my best to answer

```
cout << "What is your height(ft in)? with a space between(e.g. 5 11)";
cin >> height;
double heightconverter = height * 12.00; //HERES THE ISSUE
cout << heightconverter;
cin >> heightconverter;
system("pause\n");
return 0;
```

Comment: is this a parsing issue? you dont know how to parse and detect the input format? or a conversion issue, you dont kwow the conversion factor

Comment: What problems are you having, exactly, with taking one value, multiplying it by 12, and then adding a second value?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, where does the second value come from? If I ask them to enter their height and they enter 5 11, how would I take 11 from their string, and add it to the 5 * 12? That's basically what I'm asking about. Another example, 5 10(5"10), I would do 5 * 12, but how to take the 10 from the input, and add it into the equation?

Comment: Normally, `operator>>` is a terrible way to parse input, but in this case it's the least complicated option. Just use it twice. >> stops at whitespace. The first >> does not consume the whole input.

Answer (score 1):

You could read the *separator* as a separate character:

```
char separator;
std::cin >> feet >> separator >> inches;
```

This should handle the cases of

```
5 11
5'11
5"11
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the feet and inches separately so you can then add them up and work with only inches.

Also keep them as int as long as possible, double is not accurate.

```
int feet; int inches;
cin>>feet>>inches;

inches += feet*12;
```

Comment: "double is not accurate" what?

Comment: But wouldn't this require me to ask for two strings one being something along the lines of, "What is the first portion of your height(ft)" and then "and the second(in)"?

Comment: @jS, double will lose precision at some point and get a similar but not quite result. 0x41 even if you needed to, I dont see the issue

Comment: @gia int will lose precision one heck of a lot sooner when dividing, and double doesn't lose unit-level precision until far, far beyond the expected range of human heights.

Comment: @gia It's not really an issue, I would just assume that it would look a bit more pleasing, along with freeing up some lines of code

Comment: @gia ok, awesome! but how will it recognize that feet is before the space and inches is after?(the variables) does it just assume basically? And if were to display the result, how would I go about doing that? How would I go about storing the result into another variable and then displaying it from that variable?

Comment: yeah its a program not a mind reader, if you want to validate input you will need a parser and I dont think you are advanced enough for that

Comment: `noskipws` doesn't do what you think it does. Now you've added it, it won't read in `inches`. You can tell by [checking the state of the stream following the read](http://ideone.com/0NE2or). Note that if you remove the check it'll output that there are *60* inches, not the 71 you would expect were it working.

Comment: @gia Ah okay I see, yeah I'm still learning so a parser is out of the question. If I wanted to display the final calculation back to the user, how would I go about doing that because it's multiple variables being played with here, and I'm not sure how I can store the final calculation into a new variable like HeightInInches or something

Comment: @jaggedSpire yeah never used that, removed it. Without it, it reads fine provided there is a space between the numbers